# Posting data from one page to another

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

I am using VueJS for the first time and enjoying it.  I am trying to POST to a page, GET works fine

In my routing file I have all the routes mapped out, I am trying to post to Contracts

```
{ path: '/contract/:id',
      name: 'Contract2',
      component: Contract,
      props: true
    },
```

If I do a GET /contract?id=1 or /contract/1 both work with GET

But POST (Postman for instance)  I get

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Error</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <pre>Cannot POST /contract/</pre>
    </body>
</html>
```

My VueJS posting code (the redirect is not working either)

```
loadContract: function(contractId) {

      axios
        .post("/contract", {
          id: contractId
        })
        .then(function(response) {
          console.log(response);
          //REDIRECT TERE
          //router.go("/contract");
        })
        .catch(function(error) {
          console.log(error);
        });
    },
```

Comment: What do you mean `post` to another page? If you're talking about passing data between pages with `vue-router`, you can actually pass params when you do a programmatic navigation. Please read up on it [here](https://router.vuejs.org/en/essentials/navigation.html)

Comment: Mate, you solved it, passing values between 2 pages, please post as a solution.  Coming from a non web background, I thought of HTTP Post terminology etc

Comment: Well, processing external post requests is also a legit concern in this context. In that case, you'd want to setup server middleware to process the post request, then proceed with logic (ie render the right page).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What do you mean post to another page? If you're talking about passing data between pages with vue-router, you can actually pass params when you do a programmatic navigation. Please read up on it [here](https://router.vuejs.org/guide/essentials/navigation.html)

Example:

```
router.push({ name: 'contract', params: { contractId: 123 }})
```

Comment: I think that link might be outdated, is there a more current page you can link to that has the same information?

Comment: I've updated the link @Keara, thanks for pointing that out :)